# How to put Saudi Riyal (SAR) currency symbol in left side of currency?

Tags: microsoft-excel, currency-format

The default currency symbol format is like this:
[image]

But I want the currency symbol to be shown on the left side.

It was `#,##0.00 [$ر.س.‏-ar-SA]` in custom formatting before, and I tried changing this format to `[$ر.س.‏-ar-SA] #,##0.00` but it's still showing the same result.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: The SAR currency symbol from XE.Com is `﷼` .  The symbol from Excel includes two `dots`.  I don't know how to write currency in Arabic, but if you use the XE.Com symbol, you can use `#,##0.00﷼` and get the result you want.  I think between the dots being interpreted as a decimal, and the `right-to-left` font, there is an issue.  But this may be all off and the dots may be serving some other purpose in the Excel number format.

Answer (score 0):

use format "#,##0.00"  and just add the letters You wish before the hash,,,

ex: "SAR #,##0.00"

output example : SAR 90,200.00